# RabbitMQ. Routing configuration best practices

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmqctl

I'm using RabbitMQ in my pet project (Spring Boot based). In `@Configuration` I declare beans like `Queue`,`Binding`,`DirectExchange`. So, when I run the application all these exchanges and bindings with queues are created automatically. I'm concerned about whether this is the correct way to configure these RabbitMQ-related "entities". Should I separate this into separate steps before application startup? For example, calling series of `curl` to the management HTTP API to create all needed queues (with exchanges and bindings) before application startup. What are the best practices for creating/configuring routing-related stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is there is no one way of using RabbitMQ. However there are a few questions I always ask myself before working with any broker. I'll apply them to your question here.

**Let's question the approach:**

- In regards to creating the exchanges, bindings, queues etc:

Try to understand if the elements you are using are durable. If so, then you could create this within your code on startup & apply a simple health check. You also want to check if your RabbitMQ server persists data. If not, then you'll HAVE to create your queues, exchanges & bindings every time.

- In regards to routing & binding queues with exchanges:

There are two major questions you need to consider

1. How much does latency matter?

If latency does matter, try to use direct exchanges as much as you can. The reason for this is simple. You're simply going from exchange to queue instead of having to route your message. Routing adds latency, never forget! If those few extra ms won't make the difference for you, then the following question needs to be kept in mind to understand how to define your exchanges, bindings & queues.

2. How will I use my broker?

Some people use their broker to simply pub/sub messages. This is a perfectly reasonable use case. In this case a fanout exchange would be the most viable option. If you're trying to minimize the amount of queues you're creating a topic exchange may be interesting as well.

However more important, are you using your broker exclusively for between-service communication or is your service going to be both the producer and consumer? Hell, is it a mix between the previous two cases? This boundary needs to be defined clearly. Else you'll run into a mess where you suddenly notice you're consuming messages that can actually be handled internally by another library or simply passing arguments to functions.

**Example of how to apply it:**

Case: we have a logging service & user service:

*1. How will I use my broker:*

between service communication.

*2. Which messages do I need to get across?*

- CRUD operations
- login/logout

*3. How would my routing table look like (draft)?*

| Exchange Name | Exchange Type | Binding | Queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user | topic | user.cmd.* | user:crud |
| user | topic | user.event.login | user:login |

Above you can clearly see we can handle all CRUD operations using one simple queue. Is this the most efficient approach? It depends on your service. It may be better that `user.cmd.create` should go to `user:created`. This is another boundary that you'll need to define.

Something that also needs to be mentioned is that you should use your Queues & routing keys as pieces of information. Debugging a micro service can be hellish. So applying a general naming convention would be most appropriate. There is no one naming convention, so this depends on your use case once again.

**Conclusion:**

In general the practice that is best in regards to any broker is clearly defining the scope of your broker and its underlying elements. If not done properly, it does not matter if you do a health check or not on startup. It's easy to get lost in the complexity and interesting features rabbitMQ offers. Try to keep it as simple as possible at first and ask yourself: "is it going to cost me a lot of time to refactor/debug/fix later?" If the answer is yes go back to the first sentence in this paragraph.

**Documentation:**

AMQP concepts: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Some general best practices: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/part2-rabbitmq-best-practice-for-high-performance.html

Routing: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html

Latency & throughput: https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2012/05/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth